# How to implement a custom module in Android

Tags: java, android, oop, module, android-studio

I am having some confusion trying to best design my application. In Android Studio when I add a new module it basically seems to just create an entirely new application. I am confused on what the benefit of this could actually be. When would someone want add a module like this to their project and not simply just create a new application? Also, is it a good idea to use this feature on Android? Should I instead merely use packages and reuse my code that way? Doing an internet search has gotten me nowhere as it appears all different types of languages treat modularization and packages as somewhat different. I have always just imported classes to reuse my code, and I am afraid that I seem to be missing some fundamental OO principle by not using modules. If someone could please fill me in on what this great mystery is, or some good reading material I will be greatly appreciative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have one project for every application you develop.

If you want to use reusable modules in more than one project (which is an incredibly good software quality), you should pack a module or more in a library of reusable classes, and use those libraries in your project.

Libraries/modules should be developed in a way that they are **independent**, and they should be divided by **functionality**.

For example, you could have a module that lets you easily parse XML objects.  That would be regarded as an XML library/module.